# Open a new browser window via C# Button click

Tags: c#, web-applications, redirect, .net-4.0

Here's a little background info on what I'm trying to do:

- I have a Customer View page; on that page, there's a button to log a new call note.  Clicking this button redirects to the new call page.
- On the new call page, there's a few checkboxes that the user could select that triggers an additional action (i.e. there was a problem with their order, they have a product recommendation, etc)
- When the call note is submitted, the user is brought back to the customer view page via a `Response.Redirect`

Now, what I'm trying to do here, is that if the user selects one of the additional action checkboxes, I still want the call page to redirect back to the customer view page; however, i also want to open the corresponding additional action page in its own window.

So, the resulting flow would look something like this:

- User opens the customer page, and clicks new call.  Browser redirects to the call page
- User selects "Problem with order" and saves the call note.  The call note page redirects back to the customer view page
- The quality report page (used for issues with their order) then pops in a new window.

Googling tells me to use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`, but all those examples don't have a redirect involved in there.  Any ideas on how I could get this to work?

Comment: The idea is that you'd put some JS to launch a popup in the page you redirect to which opens the popup.

BUT that won't work because browsers (with default settings) won't let pages open popups without a user's click. What you need to do instead is launch the popup from the first page, as a result of clicking the button, like @BalaR's answer.

Or don't use popups at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need to determine that a popup in needed via javascript, and pop-up the page before the POST occurs *or* you will need to popup the page after the redirect.

To pop-up after the redirect, store some information (using `SessionState` for example) that the CustomerViewPage can check to see if a pop-up is required. If so, have the CustomerViewPage call `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to invoke the pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnClientClick` and some javascript to show the popup window.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="showPopup()" />
```

and use the `OnClick` server side event handler to do the redirection.